# C - how to poll() input without buffering?

Tags: c, io, buffer, stdin

I am trying to detect any character typed to stdin (without a newline character).

I tried :

```
setvbuf(stdin, NULL, _IONBF); //This returns 0
struct pollfd pfd = {STDIN_FILENO, POLLIN};

while (!poll(pfd, 1, ms)) {
  /* do some thing, e.g. printf("n\n"); */
}
```

It appears not stop printing when I typed <kbd>q</kbd>, but did stop after I hit <kbd>enter</kbd>. The system I am working on is arch-linux, compiler is gcc.

Comment: " tried to use setvbuf(stdin, NULL, _IONBF) and then poll(...)" --> Post that code, a [mcve]

Comment: @chux I think it was obvious enough, but I did make it more complete now.

Comment: When code does not work as expected, a early debug is to check the return values of functions like `int setvbuf()`.  Did it return 0 for you?  Since `poll()` is not standard C, post/tag the extension used like Linux?  What is [`poll()`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/poll.2.html) returning?

Comment: @chux yes, setvbuf returns 0, which should be fine. poll returns 0 when not "enter".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `q` is being held up in the *kernel's* TTY layer driver/buffer because it is in "cooked" mode.

In this mode, it will only return something to the app when the *driver* sees a newline. It then gives back: `q\n` (i.e. `q<newline>`).

To have it return immediately on *any* character, you'll have to use `ioctl` calls to put the TTY layer into "raw" mode.

You'll need to use [recommended] the `termios` calls: `tcgetattr` and `tcsetattr`

---

**UPDATE:**

> Will ioctl alone works? Which command is corresponding to change terminal into raw mode?

Look at `man termios`. It has full documentation for how to set raw mode (what is called "non-canonical" mode in the man page).

It's been a while since I've done this, but here's a skeleton function.

Although the function restores original state at the end, you might want to set non-canonical mode *once* at program start.

But, then, you'll have to handle all your own line editing (e.g. supporting backspace, etc.) for other sections of your program that want normal canonical line editing.

```
#include <termios.h>
#include <unistd.h>

void
change_tty(int fd)
{
    struct termios orig;
    struct termios raw;

    // get original cooked/canonical mode values
    tcgetattr(fd,&orig);

    // set options for raw mode
    raw = orig;
#if 0
    raw.c_lflag &= ~ICANON;
    raw.c_cc[VMIN] = ...
    raw.c_cc[VTIME] = ...
#else
    cfmakeraw(&raw);
#endif

    // put unit into raw mode ...
    tcsetattr(fd,TCSANOW,&raw);

    // do stuff in raw mode ...

    // restore original mode
    tcsetattr(fd,TCSANOW,&orig);
}
```

Comment: Will ioctl alone works? Which command is corresponding to change terminal into raw mode?

Answer (score 4):

This works for me but it may depend on your system/terminal

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <sys/ioctl.h>
#include <termios.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int main() {
    int i = 0;
    struct termios ts;
    tcgetattr(0, &ts);
    ts.c_lflag &= ~ICANON;
    tcsetattr(0, TCSANOW, &ts);
    while (!ioctl(0, FIONREAD, &i) && !i) {
        printf("x");
        fflush(stdout);
        sync();
        usleep(100);
    }
    printf("\n");
    return 0;
}
```

Craig really answered this for you.  I was just curious enough to find an implementation.  The ioctl(0, FIONREAD, &i) gets the number of characters in the buffer and puts it into i.  The man pages for termios and ioctl_tty contained all of the details needed to come up with this solution.

Honestly, though, if you are wanting to make something interactive like this, ncurses makes it somewhat simpler.