# How can I read bytes immediately from a serial port instead of waiting for a newline?

Tags: python, c, linux

I have serial to USB connection. C open /dev/ttyS0, python open /dev/ttyUSB0. C read(), 24 bytes from python. see C code below.

python send 24 bytes to C

`ser.write(b'123456789012345678901234'.encode())`

there is no print on C side.
if I add \n at the end of string.

`ser.write(b'123456789012345678901234\n'.encode())`

then on C side will print

```
 get 24 bytes
1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 0 1 2 3 4
 get 24 bytes
1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 0 1 2 3 4
 get 1 bytes
```

seems read() have to wait for '\n' in order to return from function read().

**My question is how could I let read() return after get 24 bytes?**

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <unistd.h>

typedef unsigned char uint8_t;
typedef unsigned int  uint32_t;

int fd = 0;

int main()
{
    int ret = 0;

    fd = open( "/dev/ttyS0", O_RDWR );

    if ( fd == -1 )
    {
        printf("open communication port fail");
        ret = 1;
    }

    while(1)
    {
        uint8_t buf[100]={0};
        int cnt = 0;

        cnt = read(fd, buf, 24);   

        printf(" get %d bytes\n", cnt);

        for ( int i = 0; i < cnt; i++ )
        {
            printf( "%c ", buf[i]);

        }
        printf("\n");

     }


    close(fd);

    return 0;

}
```

Comment: I think this also applies to serial ports: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54358053/c-how-to-poll-input-without-buffering - tell me if it works for you, and I'll vote to link this question to that one

Comment: @user253751 That won't take the terminal out of line mode. The terminal needs to be put in [raw mode](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/terminal-control-functions-in-python).

Comment: You are missing code to set the terminal baud rate, mode, and other options. So the terminal is in its default mode, which is line mode.

Comment: thank you all input.  seems I need config serial port as raw mode. I'll try and get back.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to suggestions in comments, generally it can be useful to put a *variable* exit condition in your `while(some_variable < some_value)` loop:
eg, from :

```
while(1)
```

to

```
int cnt = 0;//declare and initialize before loop
while(cnt < 24 )
```

You could also put a `break;` statement in the loop once  exit criteria has been met.  eg similar to:

```
    ...
    cnt = read(fd, buf, 24);
    if(cnt == 24)
    {   
        printf(" get %d bytes\n", cnt);

        for ( int i = 0; i < cnt; i++ )
        {
            printf( "%c ", buf[i]);
        }
        printf("\n");
        break;
    }
    ....
```

Answer (score 0):

inspired by all friends's input. I solved problem by set serial port by

```
stty -F /dev/ttyS0 115200 min 1 -icanon -echo
```

befor run C code, set serial port as above. then read() will read whatever available at the serial port. and return.

I do not really understand  `min 1 -icanon -echo` means, but it solved newline issue.

thank you all